# Wrong usage of d3 scale with same values in data?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, client-side

I'm new to d3 and using it for creating a simple chart using array of numbers where the value '16' appears twice in it.

It generate the chart with one 'missing' 'rect' element for the 2nd '16' value, when I check the html I see that both '16' rect has same 'y' value of 72.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, thanks

code:

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 16];

var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("class", "chart")
     .attr("width", 420)
     .attr("height", 20 * data.length);


var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
     .range([0, 420])

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(data)
     .rangeBands([0, 120]);

chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("y", y)
     .attr("width", x)
     .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to use the values from your `data` array to create range bands on an ordinal scale. Since the same input value will always be mapped to the same output value that means that both inputs `16` get mapped to the same range band `72`.

If you want each input value to be mapped to its own "bar" then you need to use array indices instead of array values.

First you prepare the indices

```
var indices = d3.range(0, data.length);    // [0, 1, 2, ..., data.length-1]
```

Then you use them to define the `y` scale domain

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(indices)
    // use rangeRoundBands instead of rangeBands when your output units
    // are pixels (or integers) if you want to avoid empty line artifacts
    .rangeRoundBands([0, chartHeight]);
```

Finally, instead of using array values as inputs use array indices when mapping to `y`

```
chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function (value, index) { 
        // use the index as input instead of value; y(index) instead of y(value)
        return y(index); 
    })
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

As an added bonus this code will automatically rescale the chart if the amount of data changes or if you decide to change the chart width or height.

Here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q8SBN/1/

Complete code:

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 16];
var indices = d3.range(0, data.length);

var chartWidth = 420;
var chartHeight = 120;

var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("class", "chart")
     .attr("width", chartWidth)
     .attr("height", chartHeight);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
     .range([0, chartWidth])

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(indices)
     .rangeRoundBands([0, chartHeight]);

chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function (value, index) { return y(index); })
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

Comment: @OriWei: If any of the answers presented here work for you then you should upvote them and accept one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting the `y` attribute of the rectangles will utilize the same value for all duplicate elements. You can use some offsetting like so:

```
chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
       return (i * y.rangeBand()) + y.rangeBand();})
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
```

Also you might have to adjust the height of your overall chart to see all the bands.