# d3.js need repeated values on y axis

Tags: d3.js, gantt-chart

I have an array:

```
taskTypes = [slot1, slot2, slot3,slot4,slot1,slot2,slot6];
```

my code for y-axis is:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(taskTypes)
    .rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .1);
```

It is showing only unique values on y-axis, I want to show the values as they are. Can you help me out with the correct code?

Comment: I want to show the values as they are .. as in repeated values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17843472/3442309) gives the basic solution: Using the ordinal scale, domain values  uniquely identify corresponding range values. In your case both the '"slot1"' input values will map to the same output value, so will not appear unique.

The solution is to use array indices `(0, 1, 2...)` instead of array values `("slot1", "slot2"...)` as your ordinal scale input domain:

```
var taskTypes = ["slot1", "slot2", "slot3","slot4","slot1","slot2","slot6"];

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(d3.range(0, taskTypes.length))
     .rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .1);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/fhf3095r/3/

Comment: hi, one more query, before this i was doing     "translate(" + x(d.actual_startDate) + "," + y(d.slotName) + ")";  where d.slotName = slot1, or slot2 or slot3 or any other value, but now after your changes y(d.slotName) is returning undefined, any suggestions??

Comment: @sachin You have to use the slot index, not name after making this change. This answer will also change your labels to numbers unless you're setting them manually, for example by using `.tickFormat(...)` on your axis object.