# d3.js gantt chart issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var taskTypes = ["slot1", "slot2", "slot3","slot4","slot1","slot2","slot6"];
```

when

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(taskTypes)
    .rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .1);
```

I was doing

```
var rectTransform = function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.termStartDate) + "," + y(d.slotName) + ")";
    };
```

and it was coming proper, but now I am taking

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(d3.range(0, taskTypes.length))
     .rangeRoundBands([ 0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ], .1);
```

and now

```
var rectTransform = function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.termStartDate) + "," + y(d.slotName) + ")";
    };
```

where `d.slotName` = slot1, or slot2 or slot3 or any other value, `y(d.slotName)` is returning undefined, any suggestions How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30052546/3442309), the domain for the `y` scale is the array indices of `taskTypes`. That means that:

```
y("slot3") = undefined
y(taskTypes.indexOf("slot3")) = 54 // Or some valid value
```

You need to determine the index of `d.slotName` in the array. Using `indexOf` won't behave well for repeated values (like `"slot1"`). If the item is present more than once, the indexOf method returns the position of the first occurence.

Comment: hi @henry.. you answered  a query on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049087/d3-js-need-repeated-values-on-y-axis   , this is the continuation of that same thing