# d3 does not show bars with repeated data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3 to display a horizontal barchart using an array of data formatted in this way

```
data = [{ value: 167, key: 'myKey' }, ...]
```

For testing I used an array of 6 elements, where the last 4 elements have the same value. d3 shows me only 3 bars, because the value of the last four elements is same and hence counted as one. 
I read the following discussion [Wrong usage of d3 scale with same values in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841437/wrong-usage-of-d3-scale-with-same-values-in-data) but I used the same code

```
y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(data.length))     // data.length = 6
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);
```

For displaying the bars I create a `g`(group element) and append a `rect` and a `text` element to it.

```
<g class="bar-container" pointer-events="all" transform="translate(0,4)">
    <rect class="bar" x="0" y="0" width="380" height="30"></rect>
    <text pointer-events="none" x="5" y="18">key</text>
</g>
```

The JS code for the update-enter-exit pattern is

```
var barsGroup = svg.selectAll('g.bar-container')
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.value; });

var bar = barsGroup.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bar-container')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')

bar.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")"; });

// Add rectangle and text
bar.append("rect") ...
bar.append('text') ...
```

There are only 3 `g` objects inside the chart not 6. Nothing is hidden so 3 additional bars are not created as I am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kindof see the fix as part of your answer itself. Look at the code you wrote here:

```
function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + y(i) + ")"; }
```

The reason you pass index to your scale is because it needs to be unique otherwise ordinal scale treats repeated values as same. However here is what you missed:

```
var barsGroup = svg.selectAll('g.bar-container')
.data(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Here your collection was grouped on values. So repeated values were considered as same and never added to the join that you expect. So barsGroup right now contains only 3 values hence remaining code works accordingly.

Now to fix this you should probably add a unique field to your data. If you do not want to do that maybe just use index here too? I don't see you using the values of 'value' directly somewhere so probably this will be fine:

```
var barsGroup = svg.selectAll('g.bar-container')
.data(data, function(d,i) { return d.i; });
```

Please correct me if this solution was wrong or does not work. I am new to this too hope this helps.

Comment: `.data(data, function(d) { return d.key; });` for the unique key name. thanks!