# D3 ignoring bars with same data despite using a key function

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to create a Bar chart and add mouseover and mouseout events on the bars. I'm using scaleBand() in my code. Therefore, from the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32597482/3766946), I gathered that ordinal scale treats repeated values as same. Therefore, I tried adding a key to the data() function which I expected would resolve the issue and give me all my bars, but that did not happen.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tooltip</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
            var bardata = [100, 200, 60, 150, 80, 300, 25, 75, 200, 50, 10, 200];

            var svgHeight = 400,
                svgWidth = 600;

            var barWidth = 30,
                barOffset = 1;

            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                           .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
                           .range([0, svgHeight-10]);

            var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                           .domain(bardata)
                           .range([0, svgWidth])
                           .paddingOuter(.5)
                           .paddingInner(.01);

            var colorYScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                                .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)*0.33,
                                            d3.max(bardata)*0.66],
                                            d3.max(bardata))
                                .range(['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']);

            d3.select('body')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', svgWidth)
                .attr('height', svgHeight)
                .style('background-color', '#eeeeee');
                
            function id (d) { return d; }
            function idx (d,i) { return i;}

            var barchart = d3.select('svg')
                             .selectAll('rect')
                             .data(bardata, function(d,i){
                                return i;
                             })
                             .join(
                                enter => {
                                    enter.append('rect')
                                         .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
                                         .attr('height', d => yScale(d))    // animate
                                         .attr('x', d => xScale(d))
                                         .attr('y', d => svgHeight-yScale(d))   //animate
                                         .attr('fill', d => colorYScale(d))

                                         .on('mouseover', function(event){
                                            d3.select(this)
                                              .style('opacity', 0.3)
                                         })

                                         .on('mouseout', function(event){
                                            d3.select(this)
                                              .style('opacity', 1)
                                         })
                                }
                             )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this an issue with the key I'm using in data()?
Or is there something more to be done while using ordinal scale to make this code work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function will make no difference in this case because the band scale is still treating different items with the same values as the same. You are actually appending 12 bars (your `barData` array length), but you don't see them because some bars — with the same value — are on top of the others.

One simple solution is passing the indices to the domain...

```
xScale.domain(d3.range(bardata.length))
```

...and then you use them:

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
```

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tooltip</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var bardata = [100, 200, 60, 150, 80, 300, 25, 75, 200, 50, 10, 200];

    var svgHeight = 400,
      svgWidth = 600;

    var barWidth = 30,
      barOffset = 1;

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(bardata)])
      .range([0, svgHeight - 10]);

    var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(d3.range(bardata.length))
      .range([0, svgWidth])
      .paddingOuter(.5)
      .paddingInner(.01);

    var colorYScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(bardata) * 0.33,
          d3.max(bardata) * 0.66
        ],
        d3.max(bardata))
      .range(['green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']);

    d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', svgWidth)
      .attr('height', svgHeight)
      .style('background-color', '#eeeeee');

    function id(d) {
      return d;
    }

    function idx(d, i) {
      return i;
    }

    var barchart = d3.select('svg')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(bardata, function(d, i) {
        return i;
      })
      .join(
        enter => {
          enter.append('rect')
            .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('height', d => yScale(d)) // animate
            .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
            .attr('y', d => svgHeight - yScale(d)) //animate
            .attr('fill', d => colorYScale(d))

            .on('mouseover', function(event) {
              d3.select(this)
                .style('opacity', 0.3)
            })

            .on('mouseout', function(event) {
              d3.select(this)
                .style('opacity', 1)
            })
        }
      )
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Have in mind that a proper solution involves creating objects with unique properties.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Could you explain what you meant by objects with unique properties in this context?

Comment: @aashima instead of an array with primitives you would have something like `[{name: "foo", value: 1}, {name: "bar", value: 2}...]`.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. Thank you. I intend to load my data from an external file.